# Ruby on Rails --Spree Ecommerce Using for dance school payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am setting up spree ecommerce and would like to use it for parents to pay for classes for their children. How do I add a teacher level to associate to their students? Is there a plugin to have a set up like Udemy so that clients can ask questions of their teachers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Spree calls plugins extensions, and the full list of actively maintained extensions can be found here https://spreecommerce.com/extensions

I took a look through and didn't see anything that looked like it would do what you need it to. My experience has taught me that it's usually better to build my own extension anyways so I can tweak it as needed. Here's a link to a tutorial that shows the basics for building your own extension https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html